# Vectors Triple Product

Tags: vectors

Good day! I have three vectors $a=[2,0,-1]$, $b=[-3,1,0]$, and $c=[1,-2,4]$. The vector triple product by formula/property,

$$a\times (b\times c) = (a\cdot c)b - (a\cdot b)c = [2,-12,26]$$

and it is $[12,-14,24]$ when I compute $b\times c$ and $a\times (b\times c)$ by using definition (determinant notation) of the cross product. Why are they different?

Answer (score 2):

Let us do it both ways and maybe you can figure out where you go wrong. We start with your first way, using the identity

$$a\times(b\times c)=(a\cdot c)b-(a\cdot b)c.$$

We have that

$$a\cdot c=(2,0,-1)\cdot(1,-2,4)=2\cdot 1+0\cdot(-2)+(-1)\cdot 4=-2$$

and

$$a\cdot b=(2,0,-1)\cdot(-3,1,0)=2\cdot(-3)+0\cdot 1+(-1)\cdot 0= -6.$$

Thus

$$(a\cdot c)b-(a\cdot b)c= (-2)\cdot(-3,1,0)-(-6)\cdot(1,-2,4)=(6,-2,0)+(6,-12,24)=(12,-14,24).$$

Now let us do it the other way. We can compute cross product as formal determinants, so, with $\hat{e}_1,\hat{e}_2,\hat{e}_3$ being our basis vectors,

$$b\times c=\begin{vmatrix}
\hat{e}_1&\hat{e}_2&\hat{e}_3\\
-3&1&0\\
1&-2&4
\end{vmatrix}=(1\cdot 4-0\cdot (-2),0\cdot1-(-3)\cdot4,(-3)\cdot(-2)-1\cdot 1)=(4,12,5).$$

Thus we have that

$$a\times(b\times c)=\begin{vmatrix}
\hat{e}_1&\hat{e}_2&\hat{e}_3\\
2&0&-1\\
4&12&5
\end{vmatrix}=(0\cdot 5-(-1)\cdot 12,(-1)\cdot4-2\cdot 5,2\cdot 12-0\cdot 4)=(12,-14,24).$$

As you can see, both methods gave us that

$$a\times(b\times c)=(12,-14,24),$$

so hopefully now you can see where you went wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your time and interest ... appreciated!!!